# Angular. Только начинаю разбираться с фреймом, не подскажете, как в Chips Autocomplete запретить повторное добавление тега

Tags: angular

https://stackblitz.com/angular/xorelylakej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

Исходя из этого примера, можно ли написать метод, не позволяющий добавить, уже выбранный чипс в инпуте, повторно? Или может у mat-chips есть встроенный метод для такой проверки.